# Get the sum of multiple columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sum

I have three columns, which I am trying to get the sum of each one returned. I can do it for one column:

```
var data = db.Test.Sum(x => x.Column1);
```

I can't figure out how to get the sum for three columns though. I tried selecting the values into and summing them, but that didn't work.

```
var data = db.Test.Select(x=> new { x.Column1, x.Column3, x.Column3}).Sum();
```

I am after the result of each column separately, not a sum of all the columns.

Comment: Would it be easier to just make them separate queries?

Comment: Yes - I could do. But I thought one query on the DB would be better than 3 performance wise.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var sums = db.Tests
    .GroupBy(x => true)
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        SumColumn1 = x.Sum(y => y.Column1), 
        SumColumn2 = x.Sum(y => y.Column2), 
        SumColumn3 = x.Sum(y => y.Column3) 
    });
```

The `GroupBy(x => true)` statement places all items into a single group. The `Select` statement the allows operations against each group. In this case the only group is a group of all items that allows us to return the `Sum` of each column.

Comment: And add a .FirstAsync()

Answer (score 0):

To get the Sum of three different columns you'll need to project the sequence to that column and get the sum three different times:

```
var sum1 = db.Test.Sum(x => x.Column1);
var sum2 = db.Test.Sum(x => x.Column2);
var sum3 = db.Test.Sum(x => x.Column3);
```

To perform this in a single DB request you can perform these projections withing the scope of another query:

```
var sums = db.Test.Take(1)
    .Select(unused => new
    {
        sum1 = db.Test.Sum(x => x.Column1),
        sum2 = db.Test.Sum(x => x.Column2),
        sum3 = db.Test.Sum(x => x.Column3),
    })
    .First();
```

Comment: @Joseph Try it and find out.  I would expect so, but it may not be enough to bother with.

Comment: This will result in three individual `select sum` statements resulting in longer execution times than the single GroupBy answer posted below.

Comment: @RobEpstein So long as it's done in a single round trip to the DB I'd expect the differences to be pretty minimal.  Summing 3 columns all at once is not particularly more or less expensive than summing 3 columns individually.  The first option would of course have 3 round trips to the database; the second option removes that drawback.